# NCache doesn't seem to contain my Session data

Tags: session, caching, web-config, ncache

In my web.config for my very simple web app I have the code:

```
<sessionState
                 cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" mode="Custom"
                 customProvider="NCacheSessionProvider" timeout="20">
            <providers>
                <add
                    name="NCacheSessionProvider"
                    type="Alachisoft.NCacheExpress.Web.SessionState.NSessionStoreProvider"
                    sessionAppId="NCacheTest"
                    cacheName="myreplicatedcache"
                    writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
                    enableLogs="false"
                    />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
```

I am adding 1000's of byte[1024] objects into the Session[] at a time using:

```
for (int count = 0; count < total; count++)
    Session[DateTime.Now.Ticks + "_" + count] = new byte[size];
```

And yet when I check my command line stats on NCache, all I get is:

```
Cache-ID:       myreplicatedcache
Scheme:         replicated-server
Status:         Running
Cluster size:   2
                bibble1:8700
                bibble2:8700
UpTime:         26/05/2010 13:23:09
Capacity:       200 MB
Count:          1

Cache-ID:       mycache
Scheme:         local
Status:         Stopped
```

Though the addtestdata.exe myreplicatedcache /c 1000 /s 1024 adds lots to the count.

My objects are still available in the session, however.

Could someone tell me what's going, please?

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it saves all session data in one object. This means, that at that moment, you have 1 active session, and all the data is stored against that session. If you create another session, the count will increase to 2.